# Rewrite date into range from array

Tags: php, arrays, max, min

I need to rewrite a range of date that each hotel room available from array. This is my array values:

```
1=2012-10-07
1=2012-10-08
1=2012-10-09
1=2012-10-10
2=2012-10-07
2=2012-10-08
2=2012-10-09
2=2012-10-10
3=2012-10-05
3=2012-10-06
3=2012-10-08
3=2012-10-09
3=2012-10-10
```

I need to write it in:

```
1 available from 7-10 October 2012 //I know this line need to use date("F Y",strtotime());
2 available from 7-10 October 2012 
3 available from 5-10 October 2012
```

Please suggest how to write these stack of days into range of date in PHP. Regards,

Comment: And what is your particular question regarding this task description?

Comment: @deceze, I need to rewrite a stack of dates into range of date.

Comment: Yes, you said as much in the question. What ***problem*** do you have doing so?

Comment: The problem is I don't know how to find the first and last value in array regarding to each index. Tried to google it but no luck.

Comment: Instead of googling I'd recommend applying some logic and programming.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this should work:

```
$dates = array('2000-10-02', '2000-10-01', '2000-10-03');
sort($dates);

// prints "1-3 October 2000"
echo date('j', strtotime(current($dates))) . '-'
   . date('j', strtotime(end($dates))) . ' '
   . date('F Y', strtotime(current($dates)));
```

Areas of improvement:

- What happens when day ranges are not consecutive?
- What happens when a range stretches across two different years or months?

Answer (score 2):

There you go http://codepad.viper-7.com/EKo9ky

```
$dates = array(
    array(1, "2012-10-07"),
    array(1, "2012-10-08"),
    array(1, "2012-10-09"),
    array(1, "2012-10-10"),
    array(2, "2012-10-07"),
    array(2, "2012-10-08"),
    array(2, "2012-10-09"),
    array(2, "2012-10-10"),
    array(3, "2012-10-05"),
    array(3, "2012-10-06"),
    array(3, "2012-10-08"),
    array(3, "2012-10-09"),
    array(3, "2012-10-10")
);
$info = array();
foreach($dates as $roominfo) {
    $time = strtotime($roominfo[1]);
    $room = $roominfo[0];
    if(!array_key_exists($roominfo[0], $info))
        $info[$room] = array($time, $time);
    if($time<$info[$room][0])
        $info[$room][0] = $time;
    if($time>$info[$room][1])
        $info[$room][1] = $time;
}

foreach($info as $roomId => $roomRange) {
    echo $roomId.' available from '.
        date('d', $roomRange[0]).' - '.
        date('d F Y', $roomRange[1]).' <br/>';
}
```

Output:

```
1 available from 07 - 10 October 2012
2 available from 07 - 10 October 2012
3 available from 05 - 10 October 2012
```

this doesn't do exactly what you want, but i think this should be enough information to reach your goal. be carefull, rooms must not be available for one day within a range, keep this in mind.

Comment: Thank you very much this kinda helpful but I need to consider the issue that @webjawns.com said as well. What if it's a different month and year! Thanks by the way.

Comment: just write a function(start, end) which returns the required information (eg. 01 June - 12 October 2012). the other point of @webjaws.com 'What happens when day ranges are not consecutive?' seems to be more challanging.

Answer (score 1):

Here is some flows on how you can accomplish your task.

First slice them according to your 1,2,3

then you could process your dates like this:

without using sort, current, end. we can just use minimum and maximum array;

```
<?php
$dates = array('2012-10-07','2012-10-10','2012-10-01');
$stimes = array_map('strtotime',$dates);

var_dump($dates);
var_dump($stimes);

echo date('F j, Y', min($stimes));
echo "<br />\n";
echo date('F j, Y', max($stimes));
```

Comment: will your code solve the problem of dates of two months or two different years?

Comment: no, it wouldnt solve the 2 months/2 years issue. You'll need to write logic for these.
How would you present the values anyway?
Would be like this=>  7 Oct - 10 Nov .
and then for the 2years =>  7 Oct 2011 - 10 Nov 2012